# trouble with Javascript while loop, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So I am doing a an exercise in which I have to sort a given string. Each word in the string contains a number in it(written like this 'H3llo'). The number that is in each word of the string should be placed in order according to the number in the new string that is to be returned.

For example if my input is "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a", then my function should return "Thi1s is2 3a T4est".

I almost cracked it but my output is incomplete. Here is my code:

```
function order(words) {
    var lst = words.split(' ');
    var count = 0;
    var n = count + 1;
    var s_n = n.toString();
    var new_l = [];
    while (count < lst.length) {
        if (lst[count].includes(s_n) === true) {
            new_l.push(lst[count])
        }
        count++
    }
    return new_l.join(' ');
}
```

When I test it, instead of getting:

```
console.log(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"));
>>> 'Thi1s is2 3a T4est'
```

I get this:

```
console.log(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"));
>>> 'Thi1s'
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sooner or later you should learn about [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: `n` and `s_n` need to be set inside the loop.

Comment: did all the suggestion so far still not working

Comment: add `;` after `count++` and `new_l.push(lst[count])` and do what @Malk told you increase `s_n` inside loop

Comment: You never change s_n. It is always "1". How do you expect to get in your output any string other than that containing "1"?

Answer (score 2):

You will basically need two `loops` - one for your current counter `count` i.e. the incremental number and another to iterate over the list of words to match that number. You increase the count only after you have finished iterating over the list.

```js
function order(words) {
  var lst = words.split(' ');
  var count = 0;
  var new_l = [];
  while (count <= lst.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
      if (lst[i].includes(count)) {
        new_l.push(lst[i])
      }
    }
    count++;
  }
  return new_l.join(' ');
}
console.log(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"));
```

Notice too that you don't need `s_n` -- the conversion is implicit, and you don't need `=== true` as this is implicit in the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

The main thing you are doing wrong is that you assign s_n to the string '1' before your loop, but you never update it within the loop. At the same time as you update count, you need to update s_n to the string of the next integer.

So you 'fixed' the part where you weren't updating the value of n or s_n within your outer loop, but the code still wont't work because you are now using count both to increment the digit you are looking for (within a word) and to increment the search through the list of words. You need an inner loop (and another variable) to increment the search.

Comment: I put   'n++' , 'count++' and 's_n = n.toString();' in the while loop and I got worse results.

Comment: Yes it still won't work unless you change the other things that are wrong with your code.